# Bokeh callback Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, arrays, python-3.x, bokeh

#### Expected behavior

In Bokeh 1.4.0,  I have a CustomJS callback function that works well but does not work in 2.x.x.  In the callback,  I am summing detector signals stored in a ColumnDataSource and updating the displayed image using a callback triggered by a CheckboxButtonGroup.

#### Observed behavior

In 2.x.x when the callback executes the source.change.emit() line I get an Uncaught RangeError: "Maximum call stack size exceeded" in the js console. It appears that the typed array for Bokeh has changed, but I don't know how to effect the same behaviour in this version.

#### Example code

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import Figure, show, output_notebook()
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CheckboxButtonGroup, CustomJS
from bokeh.layouts import column

output_notebook()

det1 = np.zeros((1000,256))
np.fill_diagonal(det1, 5)
det2 = np.empty((256, 1000))
np.fill_diagonal(det2, 3)

data = {'x': np.linspace(270, 320, 1000), 
        'y': np.linspace(0, 2560, 256),
        'image': det1,
        'det1': det1,
        'det2': det2,
        'det3': np.ones((1000, 256)),
        'det4': np.zeros((1000, 256)) -0.5
       }


delta = max(data['x']) - min(data['x'])
bins = max(data['y']) - min(data['y'])
source = ColumnDataSource(dict(image=[data['image'].T],
                               det1=[data['det1'].T],
                               det2=[data['det2']],
                               det3=[data['det3'].T],
                               det4=[data['det4'].T],
                               x=[min(data['x'])],
                               y=[min(data['y'])],
                               delta=[delta],
                               bins=[bins]))
plot = Figure(plot_width=600, plot_height=600, tools="box_select,save,box_zoom, wheel_zoom,hover,pan,reset")

plot.image(image='image', y='y', x='x', dh='bins', dw='delta', source=source,
                palette="Spectral11")



select = CheckboxButtonGroup(name="Detector Select:", labels=['1', '2', '3', '4'], active=[0])

callback_str = """
var d1 = source.data['det1'][0];
var d2 = source.data['det2'][0];
var d3 = source.data['det3'][0];
var d4 = source.data['det4'][0];
var d = source.data['image'];
var sum = new Array();

function sumArrays(...arrays) {
  const n = arrays.reduce((max, xs) => Math.max(max, xs.length), 0);
  const result = Float64Array.from({ length: n });
  return result.map((_, i) => arrays.map(xs => xs[i] || 0).reduce((sum, x) => sum + x, 0));
}

var f = cb_obj.active;
if (f.indexOf(0) > -1) {
    sum.push(d1);
}
if (f.indexOf(1) > -1) {
    sum.push(d2);
}
if (f.indexOf(2) > -1) {
    sum.push(d3);
}
if (f.indexOf(3) > -1) {
    sum.push(d4);
}
d[0] = sumArrays(...sum);

//Everything above works fine, error occurs during update of source.data['image'].
source.change.emit();
"""

select_callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code=callback_str)

select.js_on_change('active', select_callback)
layout = column(select, plot)
show(layout)
```

Answer (score 1):

Bokeh 2.x introduced a more rigorous "ndarray" type into BokehJS. It is not widely documented because it is not something the vast majority of users ever have to think or know about. The following callback code seems to work for me. (Note: I had to reduce the image size or set `det4` to `5*np.random.random((N, M))-0.5` to actually be able to really see the changes visibly)

```js
const {Float64NDArray} = Bokeh.require("core/util/ndarray")
const d1 = source.data['det1'][0];
const d2 = source.data['det2'][0];
const d3 = source.data['det3'][0];
const d4 = source.data['det4'][0];
const d = source.data['image'];
const sum = new Array();

function sumArrays(...arrays) {
  const n = arrays.reduce((max, xs) => Math.max(max, xs.length), 0);
  const result = Float64Array.from({ length: n });
  return result.map((_, i) => arrays.map(xs => xs[i] || 0).reduce((sum, x) => sum + x, 0));
}

var f = cb_obj.active;
if (f.indexOf(0) > -1) {
    sum.push(d1);
}
if (f.indexOf(1) > -1) {
    sum.push(d2);
}
if (f.indexOf(2) > -1) {
    sum.push(d3);
}
if (f.indexOf(3) > -1) {
    sum.push(d4);
}
// here is the important change
d[0] = new Float64NDArray(sumArrays(...sum), sum[0].shape);

source.change.emit();
```

A few other notes for you, regarding the upcoming Bokeh 3.0:

- The old `figure` / `Figure` dichotomy is removed. Only `figure` will exsist in Bokeh 3.0 (and it's mostly all we have ever documented anywhere for a long time)
- Deprecated `plot_width` and `plot_height` are removed, just use `width` and `height` the same as all other layout-ables.

Comment: This is great!  JS is not my strong suit, so this would've taken me ages to figure out.   I find myself needing to do this type of manipulation on embedded graphs fairly often,  hopefully the changes to bokehjs stabilize enough that there'll be some broader documenation, in future.